# What charting tools/controls would you use with SQL Server/Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

Apart from commercial tools like Dundas, are there any open source or cheaper (and decent) 3rd party charting tools/controls for reporting services out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ChartFX for ReportingServices.  It is not too expensive.

http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxSqlProducts/cfxReportingServices/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft chart controls is nice. I had used it in one of my project.

read more: http://parasdoshi1989.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/how-to-include-charts-in-visual-studio-2008-express-edition-using-microsoft-chart-control/